# How to return back from a view controller view to app delegate controller view in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, view, addsubview

I added a view with app delegate class's button click. Like this:

In UnifeyeMobile_templateAppDelegate.mm :

```
- (IBAction)onBtnImageTracking:(id)sender {

// create our UnifeyeMobileViewController and present it
UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController* unifeyeMobileViewController = [[UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController" bundle:nil];
unifeyeMobileViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[viewController presentModalViewController:unifeyeMobileViewController animated:YES];
[unifeyeMobileViewController release];
}
```

And I want to back from added UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController's view to main app delegate class view. I put a button for back. But I dont know how to do this? Please help me.

Comment: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the model viewcontollers code, simply call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For the interaction from the users, which you wish to use to dismiss the modal view (for example a button touch event).

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have a memory problem, I got an error in dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done two ways depending if you want to add some special behavior to hiding your modal view:

Simple (inside the modal view)

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to add some custom effects to hiding the modal view, let UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController hold some kind of reference to the main view. This can be achieved by making your main view implement some delegate-protocol that could look something like this:

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) hideModal:(UIViewController*) modalViewController;
```

This way, you could set a modalViewDelegate on the UnifeyeMobileImageTrackingViewController like this before you show it:

```
unifeyeMobileViewController.delegate = self;
```

Let the implementation of hideModal in the main view hide the modal view the way you like.

Hope this helps :)